# Generate uuid based on some value and retrive c#

Tags: c#, uuid

I need to generate a uuid but based on (userid+time+ip) at client side, and retrive those details from that uuid (which user passes me through phone).

What I need in detail is that user,time and ip should be encoded in uuid such a way that uuid it self does not reveal any details but after back processing it I should be able to get the details.

How to encode values in uuid and retrive them ?

**Suggested answer:(by  vivek nuna)**

*This code works fine generating uuid , but how to **retrive my userid,time and ip** back from this uuid ?*

```
string input = "userid"+"time"+"ip"; using (MD5 sha256 = MD5.Create()) { byte[] hash = sha256.ComputeHash(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(input)); Guid result = new Guid(hash); }
```

Comment: string input = "userid"+"time"+"ip";
        using (MD5 sha256 = MD5.Create())
        {
            byte[] hash = sha256.ComputeHash(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(input));
            Guid result = new Guid(hash);
        }

Comment: Once its hased how would I get the values back ?

Comment: It's not the exact code. U just encrypt the string with a key and decrypt it later with same key